# can't access model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, wcf-rest

i have this result from the restful service i have:
[image]

[image]

## NOTE: Response is in JSON format it's the plugin from chrome which displays it like that.

if you look at image two [the one above this] the models attributes is **Items** then each item are under Items. What should i do to access **item**?

my problem is i can't access or retrieve data of each item from this result. i must not change anything from the server side though. I'm using backbone with this code.

```
window.Item = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Item,
url: 'http://localhost/InterprisePOS/Product/loaditembycategory/Event Materials'
});

window.ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : 'ul',
initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind("reset",this.render,this);
},
render: function(eventName){
    _.each(this.model.models.Items, function(item){
        $(this.el).append(new ItemListItemView({model:item}).render.el);
    },this);
    return this;
}
 });

 window.ItemListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
template : _.template($("#item-list").html()),

render: function(eventName){
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
 });

 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes:{
    "":"list"
},
list:function(){
    this.itemList = new ItemCollection();
    this.itemListView = new ItemListView({model:this.itemList});
    this.itemList.fetch();
    $("#itemContainer").html(this.itemListView.render().el);
}
 });

 var app = new AppRouter();
 Backbone.history.start();
```

## UPDATE

I was able to correct the my problem with nested json objects. Now the Models attrib or my Collection is populated with individual items. But still the problems is it doesn't work and doesn't display my views.

[image]

This is the code i added:

```
parse: function(response) {
return response.Items;
}
```

## UPDATE

I Finally answered my question! horray! somehow i forgot to put "()" on render in my ItemListview. and also `$("#ItemContainer")` doesn't seem to work so i made it to `$('#ItemContainer)` now i'm displaying the Details from my model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that Backbone by default uses JSON for all requests and has no idea what to do with XML, you'll probably need to override the sync method for the collection in order to us use XML.

The following should be helpful in addressing your issue: http://newcome.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/consuming-xml-web-services-in-backbone-js-using-jath/

They use a 3rd party library xml parser in the sync parse operation which converts the model to JSON which Backbone can use natively.

Comment: No. the response is in JSON format. Somehow i added a plugin on chrome which makes that into what you the image is displaying but i'm sure the response is in JSON.

Comment: You don't need to override the sync. You merely have to pass options to fetch and save to deal with XML. For instance with fetch, you'd do something like this: 

this.model.fetch({
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "xml",
    processData : false
}); Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the response is returned as JSON. Backbone works on JSON data by default.

Comment: It is in JSON format. just the plugin from chrome which makes it like that. :)